# Django Error - No module named context_processors

Tags: python, django

Just today I upgraded from Django 1.7 to 1.9.1, I have cleared all the other warnings however I am stuck with one that is preventing me from progressing. If anyone has any ideas as to what is causing this error that would be great, just let me know if you need to see any other code. Thanks!

Full Traceback -

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.9.1
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'main',
 'listings',
 'profiles',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Other folders\Desktop\Student Job Search\code\opus_jobs_project\main\views.py" in index
  8.     return render(request, 'index.html', context_dict)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  97.         return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  95.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  204.                 with context.bind_template(self):

File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py" in __enter__
  17.             return self.gen.next()

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py" in bind_template
  256.         processors = (template.engine.template_context_processors +

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in __get__
  33.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in template_context_processors
  105.         return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in <genexpr>
  105.         return tuple(import_string(path) for path in context_processors)

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py" in import_string
  20.     module = import_module(module_path)

File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named context_processors
```

Template Settings - (I have a feeling the error may be around here or at least this may link to it)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            TEMPLATE_PATH
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
                'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],

        },
    },
]
```

Comment: at least one of the lines of code you've included isn't a valid context processor, i'd suggest commenting them out one by one to discover which it is

Comment: Thanks Sayse, that worked. It was actually the two allauth ones that were breaking it. So far the website seems to be working fine without them however I was fairly sure they were essential so I will have to look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention in the comments, it was the `allauth` context processors that were causing the issues, I looked them up and they're no longer needed

From [allauth changelog](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/stable/changelog.html?highlight=context#from-0-21-0)

> Template context processors are no longer used. The context processor for allauth.account was already empty, and the context processor for allauth.socialaccount has been converted into the {% get_providers %} template tag.